# Why is "php artisan serve" closing ports ? (also not staying on 8000)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, serve

```
[Thu Feb  4 09:15:19 2021] PHP 7.4.9 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
[Thu Feb  4 09:15:26 2021] 127.0.0.1:64135 Accepted
[Thu Feb  4 09:15:26 2021] 127.0.0.1:64136 Accepted
[Thu Feb  4 09:15:34 2021] 127.0.0.1:64135 Closing
[Thu Feb  4 09:15:34 2021] 127.0.0.1:64136 Closing
[Thu Feb  4 09:15:34 2021] 127.0.0.1:64139 Accepted
[Thu Feb  4 09:15:34 2021] 127.0.0.1:64140 Accepted
[Thu Feb  4 09:15:34 2021] 127.0.0.1:64141 Accepted
```

At start everything looks fine, Dev server starts on the right port but when I access any page of the project this is happening. I have this issue on 3 machines (all three of them are running Windows) so I guess this can be a Windows issue maybe ?
I have to mention that everything works fine even if this is happening, but sometime the project is running slow because of the opening and closing ports and it looks like there is a performance issue somewhere but there is not, it's just Opening and Closing.

Also tried to serve on another port 9000, 8081, 8080 etc. but it's the same situation it's starting on the port it's served on and then jumps to 55xxx or 64xxx and keeps closing and accepting ports.

Projects are on Laravel 7 and 8, PHP version 7.4.9, Windows 10 (latest updates).

Comment: Can you provide more information about your development environment
Are you using WAMP, docker, homestead php installed in your machine?

Comment: I'm using Laragon on all 3 machines

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
```

OR

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public/
```

Check them by changing your port number.

Comment: `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public/
[Thu Feb  4 10:11:17 2021] PHP 7.4.9 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
[Thu Feb  4 10:11:23 2021] 127.0.0.1:65098 Accepted
[Thu Feb  4 10:11:23 2021] 127.0.0.1:65099 Accepted
[Thu Feb  4 10:11:24 2021] 127.0.0.1:65098 Closing
[Thu Feb  4 10:11:24 2021] 127.0.0.1:65101 Accepted
[Thu Feb  4 10:11:24 2021] 127.0.0.1:65102 Accepted`